# Dropdownlist not highlighting the given value

Tags: c#, .net

i have a dropdown list which i want to highlight  a item from it. i have given the condition correct as par to me.But it didnt highlight the given item,instead showing normally as other items.

```
 DataTable dtt = new DataTable();
                dtt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
                ddlCompanyName.DataSource = dtt;
                ddlCompanyName.DataTextField = "COMPANYNAME";
                ddlCompanyName.DataValueField = "COMPANYID";
                foreach (ListItem item in ddlCompanyName.Items)
                {

                    if (item.Text == compidd)
                    {
                        item.Attributes.Add("style", "background-color:#3399FF;color:white;font-weight:bold;");
                    }
                }
                ddlCompanyName.DataBind();
                ddlCompanyName.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select Name--"));
```

> Compidd(string) has specified item to be highlighted in dropdownlist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do `DataBind` before the loop:

```
ddlCompanyName.DataBind();
foreach (ListItem item in ddlCompanyName.Items)
{
  if (item.Text == compidd)
  {
     item.Attributes.Add("style", "background-color:#3399FF;color:white;font-weight:bold;");
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

To set the value as default value you can try like this

```
ddlCompanyName.SelectedValue = "The value which you want to set as default"
```

Comment: how can i set that value as default value(i.e)

Comment: @AbrahamLincoln:- You can try to set it like `ddlCompanyName.SelectedValue = "The value which you want to set as default"`

Comment: its been working out for the highlight property...nut for default value its showing ,parameter not available in compidd\

Answer (score 2):

The `ddlCompanyName.DataBind();` must be executed before you loop the items:

```
ddlCompanyName.DataBind();
foreach (ListItem item in ddlCompanyName.Items)
{
    if (item.Text == compidd)
    {
        item.Attributes.Add("style", "background-color:#3399FF;color:white;font-weight:bold;");
    }
}
```

Otherwise there are no items in the `DropDownList`.